# Using Lift 2.1 on Google App Engine with Scala 2.8

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, scala-2.8, lift

I'm trying to use Lift 2.1-SNAPSHOT on Google App Engine but the lift snippets in the HTML are not being processed. It simply returns the HTML file.

This is the lift.html file (just a simple test):

```
<lift:surround with="default" at="content">
  Welcome to your Lift application
</lift:surround>
```

The web.xml has:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LiftFilter</filter-name>
    <display-name>Lift Filter</display-name>
    <description>The Filter that intercepts lift calls</description>
    <filter-class>net.liftweb.http.LiftFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LiftFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The appengine-web.xml contains:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>kivanotify</application>
    <version>6</version>
    <static-files/>
    <resource-files/>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties"/>
    <property name="in.gae.j" value="true" /> 
    </system-properties>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <static-files> 
        <exclude path="/static/**" /> 
    </static-files> 
</appengine-web-app>
```

When running the project using " /opt/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.6/bin/dev_appserver.sh target/kivanotify" and accessing the url http://localhost:8080/lift.html is simple returns the lift.html as is without processing the  tags.

Any idea why the  tags are not being processed? There is no logging that hints at a problem.

Regards,
Gero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember you need the following setting in appengine-web-app.xml.

```
  <static-files>
    <exclude path="/**" />
  </static-files>
```

BTW, I found stax.net is much Lift-friendly then GAE.

Comment: Stax.net is now Cloudbees.com.